# Prove uniform convergence of $f_n = \frac {x} {1+x^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series

$$f_n = \frac {x} {1+x^n}     ,    x \in [0,\infty)$$

I'm not sure what cases I have here. I thought maybe to check whenever n is odd or not ...

thanks for the help !

Comment: Usually you want to split it into something like $[0,1]$ and everything else because of the existence of powers. The inequalities tend to behave differently in those pieces even if the end result is the same. You also want to check the endpoints where you split the intervals as funny things can happen at them..

Comment: @MaikPicki quite but that doesn't tell you what it's coverging to. The behavior is different between $[0,1)$, at $1$, and on $(1,\infty)$.

Comment: @CameronWilliams can you be more specific please ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointwise limit is $$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x&0\leq x<1\\
0.5 &x=1\\
0 &x>1\end{cases}$$

Can you conclude now?

$\textbf{Added}$:

Here, each $f_n$ is continuous but $f$ is not continuous (at $1$ ), so the convergence is not uniform. More generally, the
convergence cannot be uniform on any domain containing $1$.

Comment: and now for each case I have to check uniform convergence?

Comment: No! Each $f_n$ is continuous and if the convergence is uniform, then $f$ must be continuous. Is our  $f$ continuous ?

Comment: Very good not to believe without distrust in titles of problems.....